# Auto closing socket python

Tags: python, sockets

I wonder if when I shutdown my program , the socket I have made inside it close automatically or they take place in the memory ?
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the threads in your program terminate, the socket will be closed.